# A Cyclic quadrilateral's distance program

Tags: python-2.7

Can Somebody help me:

```
#Program to find the area and perimeter of any quad

#First find length of 2 points using distance formula
print "This program is to find the perimeter of a quadrilateral."
print "Tell me the points, In order that the first set of points is on the top left, the second set of points is on the bottom left, the third set of points is on the bottom right, and the fourth set of points is on the top right"
a = int(raw_input("First x-coordinate point is... "))
b = int(raw_input("First y-coordinate point is... "))
c = int(raw_input("Second x-cordinate point is..."))
d = int(raw_input("Second y-coordinate point is..."))
e = int(raw_input("Third x-coordinate point is..."))
f = int(raw_input("Third y-coordinate point is..."))
g = int(raw_input("Fourth x-coordinate point is..."))
h = int(raw_input("Fourth y-coordiante point is..."))
i = ((c-a)**(2) + (d-b)**(2))**(0.5)
j = ((g-e)**(2) + (h-f)**(2))**(0.5)
k = ((e-c)**(2) + (f-d)**(2))**(0.5)
l = ((g-a)**(2) + (h-b)**(2))**(0.5)

#Then find the perimeter of a quad adding the four points.
m = i + j + k + l
print m

#Finally, find the area of the quad using brahmagupta's formula.
n = m / 2
o = (n-i)(n-j)(n-k)(n-l)**0.5
print o
```

On the second to last line, it gives me a syntax error stating "float object is not callable"

Comment: By asking you for the answer, I meant that you could give me ideas on how to do it. Sorry for not being specific. And this is not my hw, just an idea I came up with and decided to do over spring break. Sorry again on my behalf.

Comment: Most programming languages don't do implicit multiplication (Python is no exception) and require a `*` between terms to be multiplied.  Hence: `o = (n-i)*(n-j)*(n-k)*(n-l)**0.5`.  Assuming `**` is the power operator, that takes the square root of one term, not of the product of 4 terms.  Hence really: `o = ((n-i)*(n-j)*(n-k)*(n-l))**0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the multiplication operators in this line:

```
o = (n-i)(n-j)(n-k)(n-l)**0.5
```

Which should be

```
o = (n-i)*(n-j)*(n-k)*(n-l)**0.5
```

However, the last term will take the square root only of the last term in brackets. For Brahmagupta's formula you want the square root of the whole expression, in which case you need this:

```
o = ((n-i)*(n-j)*(n-k)*(n-l))**0.5
```